# Working with line delimited JSON strings in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I am using an API which requires I send it data as new line delimited JSON, for example;

```
{"id":"67523", "name":"Jason"}
{"id":"69928", "name":"Doug"}
```

The API accepts single JSON objects, but can accept multiple new line delimited JSON objects in a single batch (more efficient). How do you construct string objects like the above in PHP?

If taking a string like `{"id":"67523", "name":"Jason"}`, I can `json_decode()` it to turn it into an associative array (this is accepted by the API endpoint). However, the only way I can see to pass a number of these objects together is within an array, but the API does not accept an array of JSON objects.

Comment: I would re-check your facts. JSON is simple until you try to muck about with it like you seem to be suggestion the api requires. Either you or the API developer has got confused. I am guessing its you that have got confused

Comment: Maybe you should point us at the API Documentation

Answer (score 1):

If API really accepts newline delimited objects, and manage objects over json level, try:

```
$data = '{"id":"67523", "name":"Jason"}'."\r\n".'{"id":"69928", "name":"Doug"}';
```

In php also you can use new lines just inside string code.

Comment: This seems to be the proper answer to this curious case. The API developer is combining two things here I think.

Comment: I have tried this, but unfortunately it fails with the API citing "invalid JSON". When using this method, I read my JSON strings from a file (line by line), appending them to the `$payload` in a loop: `$payload .= $line . "\r\n";`

Comment: Maybe API has error at latest empty string, what may going if you add "\n\r" at latest payload in request too. No add \n\r if its is latest element.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to `json_encode` each individual object/array. However, you can do this in such a way that you don't have to concat each individual object.

```
$a = ['id' => 67523, 'name' => 'Jason'];
$b = ['id' => 69928, 'name' => 'Doug'];

echo implode("\r\n", array_map('json_encode', [$a, $b]))
```

Output:

```
{"id":67523,"name":"Jason"}\r\n
{"id":69928,"name":"Doug"}
```

Answer (score -1):

JSON does not allow real line-breaks.
As you said API is accepting Single Objects and not accepting an array of JSON objects, the below Code will help you somewhat where each object is given index

```
{
  0: {
    "id": "67523",
    "name": "Jason"
  },
  1: {
    "id": "69928",
    "name": "Doug"
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand JSON does not allow new line breaks; this API accepts multiple individual JSON objects, separated by new lines as explained in the question

Comment: i think you should point us to your API Documentation,The approach towards your solution might be different  as said above by @RiggsFolly  "Either you or the API developer has got confused. I am guessing its you that have got confused".